# Performance drop with GL_LINES?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, freeglut

I tried to draw a simple line in OpenGL:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <freeglut.h>

float startX = -180.0f;
float startZ = -100.0f;

float qtyX = 36;
float qtyZ = 20;

float red = 0.0f, green = 0.0f, blue = 0.0f;

void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluLookAt(0.0, 50.0f, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0);

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(50.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f);
    glEnd();

    //glutWireSphere(20.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f);

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glFlush();
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-64.0, 64.0, -36.0, 36.0, 10, 10000.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(1280, 720);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I run the program, the performance drop significantly then after a few seconds, it stops responding (I have to run task manager and force quit the program). However, when I disable the line and draw the glutWireSphere (or a polygon), the performance is normal.

Is there a problem with my code? Or perhaps GL_LINES is deprecated?

Windows 10, 1070 MaxQ, Visual Studio

Comment: Hello there, and welcome. You need to provide significantly more info to get proper answers. "drops significantly" compared to what? what's the performance baseline? "stops responding" is probably something to do with handling OS events, you have absolutely no info on how display is called.

Comment: *"Or perhaps GL_LINES is deprecated?"* - `glutWireSphere` is deprecated, too.

Comment: Please show us the rest of your code. I have a suspicion what might cause this, but it's hard to tell without seeing the rest (has to do with how the main loop event gathering (GetMessage) may be used by drivers and libraries to trigger cleanup).

Comment: Hi, here is the full code: 

https://pastebin.com/p1yT2E0D

I'm still struggling to find out what is the problem. I've tested drawing polygons and it runs fine. Only GL_LINES makes the program not responding.

Comment: your "full code" draws quads, not lines. So it's not what's slow...

Comment: Sorry, that was the revision I made earlier. Here is the original one

https://pastebin.com/dVmsX9zh

Comment: All that you've shown looks reasonable. If you attach a debugger and break it, where does it stop?